# Re-opening an old question doesn't remove the notice about the question not being a duplicate

Tags: bug, reopened-questions

I [re-opened an old question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/41734/revisions), since the duplicated question was automatically deleted. Once re-opened, the question still shows the link to the duplicate question, as you can see on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41734/how-to-enable-user-signatures-in-drupal-commons-qa-section

> [image: screenshot]

Since the question was re-opened, the link to the duplicated question should be removed, as it always happens.

Comment: Should it _always_ be removed, you think?

Comment: Fatal error: too many duplicate duplicate words!